# JAX-WS Servlet destroy()

Tags: java, servlets, jax-ws

I have some resources that I allocate when my web service is created that I need to be released (for example, I need to flush and close file streams when the servlet is being shut down).  How can I have code executed when the JAX-WS servlet's `destroy()` method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a `ServletContextListener` for this. Write a custom implementarion of that interface which does what you want, and then hook it into your `web.xml` using the `<listener>` element ([example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-work-with-servletcontextlistener.html)).

This lifecycle doesn't exactly match that of the servlet, but it should be close enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that you can annotate a method with `@PreDestroy`; from the JavaDoc:

> The PreDestroy annotation is used on methods as a callback
>   notification to signal that the instance is in the process of being
>   removed by the container. The method annotated with PreDestroy is
>   typically used to release resources that it has been holding. [...]

See [Creating a Simple Web Service and Clients with JAX-WS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)